# How do I produce a tab separated file from a text file?

Tags: linux, text, sed, tr

I've got a file with numbers on odd lines and text on even lines like this:

```
123123
string A
456456
string B
789789
string C
```

I want to get it to this format (tab separated):

```
123123    string A
456456    string B
789789    string C
```

I tried to remove all newlines with

```
tr -s -d " " < myFile
```

then use `sed` with

```
sed -i 's/[0-9]\s/' myFile
```

but without great success.

Can you help me get this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to use [`paste`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/paste/) as follows:

```
paste - - < myFile
```

In this command, `paste` reads the file from stdin and combines every two lines (that's what the two "-" are for) into a single line separated by a tab.

Comment: Excellent. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Yo can try the following:

```
paste <(grep -E '^[[:digit:]]+' myFile) \
      <(grep -E '^[[:alpha:]]+' myFile) \
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sed '$!N;s/\n/\t/' inputfile
```

This would join the lines separated by a <kbd>TAB</kbd> character.

Example:

```
$ seq 10 | sed '$!N;s/\n/\t/'
1   2
3   4
5   6
7   8
9   10
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk 'NR%2{printf "%s\t", $0;next}1' file
123123  string A
456456  string B
789789  string C
```

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -pe 'chomp; $_ = ($. % 2) ? sprintf "%s\t", $_ : sprintf "%s\n", $_;' file
```

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
c=0
while read a; do
    ((c++))
    if ((c%2)); then
        printf "%s\t" "$a"
    else
        echo "$a"
    fi
done < file
```